# Powershell Create and Export Root Cert PFX

Tags: powershell, x509certificate2, pfx

Apologies ahead of time if I don't get syntax correct. This is my first pass at certificate creation.

I am attempting to use Powershell to create a root certificate. I am using the following code:

```
$todaydt = Get-Date
$50years = $todaydt.AddYears(50)
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "*******" -Force -AsPlainText

$rootCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=127.0.0.1' -KeyExportPolicy Exportable  -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign,DigitalSignature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyUsageProperty All -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA'  -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256'  -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'  -notafter $50years

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $rootCert -FilePath c:\temp\my.pfx -Password $mypwd -ChainOption EndEntityCertOnly -NoProperties -Verbose
```

When I run it I get: Export-PfxCertificate: Cannot export non-exportable private key.

According to someone else in the same situation they found it to be essentially a permissions issue and solved it by:

> "I checked the option "manage private keys" and you just get the
> permissions to see - so I added my admin account...."

And then they were able to export. I am not sure what this means though? Anyone have an idea or another answer?

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax is correct and the command flow is correct. I just copied/pasted the code in my console, everything succeeded. Make sure if you run same code as posted in your question. Though, generating CA certs in PowerShell never was a good idea, you should use specialized CA software to create and run CAs.

Comment: Your code sample worked fine for me too on Windows 10 in PowerShell 5.1.  Assuming you're on Windows, run MMC.exe as an administrator, add the Certificates snap-in, select "Computer account" context, press Finish, press OK, expand Certificates - (Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates, right-click on your "127.0.0.1" cert, select All Tasks > Manage Private Keys... If you do not see this option, then you may need to contact your system administrator.  Otherwise, ensure your account has Full access to export the private key to a PFX file.

Comment: I am able to see that option.